# How to find IP address just with session IDs?

Tags: php, session, ip, sessionid

Actually it's a simple question but I couldn't asked the correct question to google maybe. Here is the problem: 
 
Think that I have  a website to which clients connect. I store session IDs (ie sbf1qql1qikvr4vnsvbomr1d61) for each connected client and I want to retrieve IP adresses using these session IDs. I'm running a php code

```
root@34s:~# php checkSessions.php
```

on the server machine. And `checkSessions.php` has a code similiar to the following snipplet

```
//Enter an infinite loop
while(1)
{
            //Get session ids and user ids from the database 
    $q1 = $db->getQ("SELECT user_id, session_id, FROM all_sessions");
    foreach($q1 as $q)
    {
        if($q[0]==63)
        {
                         // Now, I need to get IP adress. I only have a session id
        }
    }

           // Wait 2 seconds and do the same procedure again 
       sleep(2);
}
```

So, could you provide any method to find out the IP adress of the client using this session ID.

Comment: Sessions are not related to IP addresses, and cannot be used to determine an IP address.  (This is why a session fixation attack doesn't require you to spoof the victim's IP address.)

Comment: Ok, one question then: Can I find out all connected ip addresses somehow just using php console?

Answer (score 2):

Sessions do not store IP addresses or any other extra information. You need to add it to the session when it is started. ie:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```